# POV( Persistence of vision ) : Syncing the Refresh rate of LEDs with rotation

Tags: pov

I am trying  to make a POV globe and my block diagram is the following:
[image]

The goal was to  make one without using microcontrollers and using basic components available. My main query is that :

What would be the refresh rate of LEDs between different states and how to calculate a particular value so as to sync it with the rotating ring?

Answer (score 1):

The title is much more clear than the question. You need a sensor that will output a strobe each time the angle is 0. There are proximity sensors or photointerrupters,  all kinds of sensors. Then having a strobe do whatever you want in electronics.